# How to use value from a textfield in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to take a value user entered in textfield and perform sin of it when the user presses a button and display it on another textfield in android studio.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

tf1 is the TextField from which you want to take value and tf2 is the TextField in which you want to copy the value of tf1

Java file code:

```
tf2.setText(tf1.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

First Initialize your `EditText`

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
```

then get the user entered value/text like,

```
editText.getText();
```

then display another EditText/TextView as,

```
textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
```

this may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an EditText

in your layout insert an EditText like this

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and retrieve it in your activity

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

then you can get the text doing

```
String editTextContent = editText.getText().toString();
```

now if you want to pass data from a field to another for example on the user click on a button you can doing something like this

```
<!--layout.xml-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/second_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="press"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

then in your activity

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText secondEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second_edit_text);
            secondEditText.setText(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

instead of the second EditText you can use a TextView

Answer (score 0):

I really think you need to learn more about this and do some research before asking questions here.

```
EditText angleView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.angle_text_view_id);
EditText sinOfAngleView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sin_text_view);
double angle = Double.parseDouble(angleView.getText().toString());
double sinOfAngle = Math.sin(angle);
// you can set the number of digits in the decimal using the "%,.nf" as
// shown where its 3 here
sinOfAngleView.setText(String.format("%,.3f", sinOfAngle));
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `example_activity.xml` file declare a `EditText` instead of a `TextView` component:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editInp"
        android:hint="@string/hello_world"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
```

Then on your `example_activity.class` you must declare a variable of type `EditText` and instanciate it using the id you wrote on the `example_activity.xml` file:

```
EditText edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editInp);
```

Then you can store the value on a String variable:

```
String textOfEdit=edit.getText().toString();
```

I recommend you to take a look at the [Android developer](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) website for these first steps.

Hope its helps.

Answer (score 0):

XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/relMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etMain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Main EditText"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etChild"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Main"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCopy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Copy Text" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Java file contains following code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
private EditText etMain,etChild;
private Button btnCopyText;

     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


            etMain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMain);
            etChild=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etChild);
            btnCopyText=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCopyText);
            btnCopyText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                etChild.setText(etMain.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
 }
```